# What is the design logic for postgresql to not provide the construct as 'create database IF NOT EXISTS dbname'?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, ddl, ordbms

I know that it is not available in PostgreSQL, I'll request the justification only why this helpful is not provided in it which is available in other RDBMSs.
Though, it can be implemented using the programing languages having interfaces to PostgreSQL, there may be a specific reason that the designers have taken this decision to exclude it. I wish to know the merits of excluding this construct.

The other answers to similar questions seems to highlight how to mimic it using other ways. I'm not expecting that. I just want the design logic for this. If I've missed any such question, which has an answer to this point, please point me to that.

Comment: I don't know that this is an (infintely long?) design document descirbing all the features that have NOT been built. If you are interested for more details you could check the wiki, mailing list archives, code comments and history or post yourself on the mailing list asking the actual developers. If you feel the feature really is super-useful you can of course always code it yourself or pay someone else to - that's the beauty of open-source.

Comment: I'm going to say it is a case of 'getaroundtoits' as [DROP DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html) has `IF EXISTS`. Just not something that enough people have complained about or wanted to put the effort into building.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this thread on the pgsql-hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/MEYP282MB1669A5EEBC791F927D89063EB6009%40MEYP282MB1669.AUSP282.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM) about an attempt to introduce that feature:

> FWIW, I'm generally hostile to CREATE IF NOT EXISTS semantics across
> the board, because of its exceedingly squishy semantics: it ensures
> that an object by that name exists, but you have exactly no guarantees
> about its properties or contents.  The more complex the object, the
> bigger that problem becomes ... and a whole database is the most
> complex sort of object we have.  So IMV, the fact that we don't have
> this "feature" is a good thing.
>
> We do have DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS, and I think using that followed
> by CREATE is a much better-defined approach.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz Albe for your help, but then the same designers have implemented / approved the similar construct for create table as mentioed at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html which is in contrast to the justification given here. Further, as given in the quoted text, it is also there for drop database. Which, I do not know if it is consistant with that claim !

Comment: Yes, it is consistent.